# Google maps API in a virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, google-oauth

Is there a trick to using my Google Maps API key in a virtual environment?  I am getting a "key error" when I try to access my Maps API key.

[image: Maps API key error]

My API has restrictions to allow only HTTP referrers.  I have authenticated my computer to Google Cloud (I can access my Google DataStore).

Here is the code I am running in Python.  I am using Bokeh for the plot generation.

```
def location(request):
import os
from bokeh.models import GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap

client = datastore.Client()
query = client.query(kind='locData')
query.order = ['-ts']
resultList = list(query.fetch())
i = 0
lat = []
lng = []
for each in resultList:
    lat.append(each['lat'])
    lng.append(each['lng'])
    i += 1
result = i
data = dict(lat=lat, lng=lng)

title = "Location"
plot = figure(title = title,
    plot_width = 400,
    plot_height = 400)

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=45, lng=-118, map_type='roadmap', zoom=11)
api_key = os.environ['... key hidden ...'] 

plot = gmap(api_key, map_options, title="Travels")
plot.circle(x='lng', y='lat', size=15, fill_color='blue',fill_alpha=0.8, source=data)

#store components
script, div = components(plot)

#feed components to django template
return render_to_response('dashboard/singleplot.html',
    {
        'script': script,
        'div': div,
        'date': datetime.now(),
        'data': result
    }
)
```

Comment: Are you actually putting the *value* of the key in `os.environ['... key hidden ...'] ` ? That should be passed the *name of an environment variable* that has the key as its value. Of course, if you have the value of the key already, you don't need to look up anything in `os.environ` just pass it directly to `gmap`

Comment: I removed the "os.environ[" and used my API key directly and that worked except I'm getting a "referrerNotAllowedMapError" now.  But I think that is progress.  Thanks

Comment: i'd suggest updating your question so these comments can be deleted, it's more likely someone will be able to help with a single concise question.